# VBScript to access last RefreshDate on OLEDBConnection

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, msdn

I have a script written in VBScript that basically opens an Excel file, refreshes all its queries, loops over each connection to see if it's still refreshing and closes the file.

Sometimes, a query never refreshes nor goes to a **Refreshing** state so my scripts fails to refresh and fails to flag that there was a problem. To solve this I'd like to know what was the last time the query was refreshed, through RefreshDate ([documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oledbconnection-refreshdate-property-excel)). However, RefreshDate seems to fail to retrieve anything. This property of OLEDBConnection seems to work in C# and VB, but I can't find any MSDN documentation on VBS specifically.

This is my code:

```
Dim xlApp : Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim xlBook : Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
xlBook.RefreshAll
Dim connection, oledbc, i           
For i = 1 to xlBook.Connections.Count
    Set connection = xlBook.Connections.Item(i)
    If (mid(connection.Name,1,5) = "Query" or mid(connection.Name,1,11) = "Power Query") Then ' => exclude Power Pivot's data model
        Call logTrace (objLogFile,"Query name " & connection.Name) ' => this works well and returns the query name
        Set oledbc = connection.OLEDBConnection
        Call logTrace (objLogFile,"Query is refreshing " & oledbc.Refreshing) ' => this also works and returns true/false depending on whether the query is refreshing
        Call logTrace (objLogFile,"Query last refresh date " & oledbc.RefreshDate) ' => this fails to print anything
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is `On Error Resume Next` specified somewhere by any chance?

Comment: Ups... yes. I commented it out and it gives me a "Microsoft VBScript Runtime error: Unknown runtime error". On Err.Number/Description I get "70/Permission denied" any idea @Mat'sMug? Could it be the privacy level set up in Power Query? I have it on "Organizational"

Comment: No idea, but at least you know where to look (permissions) - protip: `On Error Resume Next` hides errors - don't use it for any code that can throw an error you can't afford to ignore.

Comment: So `RefreshDate` not returning anything was correct: it's not refreshing, it's hitting a *permission denied* error while connecting :)

Comment: Not sure about that, the oledbc.Refreshing works, it's the RefreshDate which doesn't seem to be a supported attribute for OLEDB in vbscript

Comment: Well, if the refresh succeeded, you could just log `Now` as the last refresh date and call it a day, no?

Comment: Sometimes a particular connection doesn't get refreshed for some reason (e.g. data changed on the backend so query fails). In those cases I want to flag that this happened